# Arrow function implicit return using logical AND

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any side effect (adverse effect) to using an implicit `return` statement in an arrow function utilizing a logical AND operator `&&`?

This might include problems with bundlers, or with optimizers removing code

**Examples:**

```js
// With return 
const tap = fn => val => {
    fn(val);
    return val;
  };
```

```js
// Without explicit return
const tap = fn => val => fn(val) && val;
```

```js
// In case fn(val) returns a falsy value
const tap = fn => val => (fn(val) || true) && val;
```

```js
// Comma sequence (added from accepted answer)
const tap = fn => val => (fn(val), val);
```

Comment: The only (but significant) adverse effect would be its negative impact on readability. Leave that sort of thing to the minifiers, IMO

Comment: Alternatively, use the comma operator -- `(fn(val), val)` -- but for readability the block with `return` is the preferred choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any side effect (adverse effect) to using an implicit return statement in an arrow function utilizing a logical AND operator &&?

Yes, there are a couple:

1. The maintenance hazard you flag up in your question: If `fn(val)` returns a falsy value, *that* value, not `val`, will be what the arrow function returns. Someone editing the logic of `fn` is unlikely to be aware that code elsewhere assumes it always returns a truthy value.
2. Another maintenance hazard is that adding another call or other logic to the arrow function is more complicated if you have to pick apart a `&&` expression to do so.
3. Subjectively, this sort of thing can be harder to read, particularly as it appears that the `&&` has significance beyond merely make it possible to avoid writing `return`.

You can address #1 by using (or some would say *ab*using) the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
const tap = fn => val => (fn(val), val);
```

**I am not recommending that,** merely noting that it's an option. The comma operator evaluates its left-hand operand, throws away that result, evaluates its right-hand operand, and takes that result as its result. You need the `()` around the expression when using a comma expression as an arrow concise body, because otherwise the concise body ends at the comma. That means the only typing you're saving is the word `return`.

> This might include problems with bundlers, or with optimizers removing code

Only if those bundlers or optimizers had bugs in them. Their *job* is to correctly understand the code. Concise arrow bodies aren't outside of that remit.

But speaking of tools: In general, I suggest writing your code as *clearly* as possible. Leave the process of making it as *brief* as possible to minifiers.